# Django: Accessing Many to Many object through another Many to Many relationship

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-views

I have simplified my models down a to make it clearer what I am trying to do.

(models.py in app Teams)

```
 from django.db import models
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 import datetime

class Team(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    team_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    team_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.team_title
```

(models.py in app Documents)

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Document(models.Model):    
   teams = models.ManyToManyField("Teams.Team", blank=True)
   document_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   document_description = models.TextField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.document_title
```

What I want to achieve is getting a list of users who have are associated with a Document by first getting all the teams associated with the document and then from this getting all the users associated with those teams.

My attempts so far have gone something like this

(view.py in app Documents)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from Documents.models import *
from Teams.models import *

def docUsers(request, doc_id):
    current_document = Documents.objects.get(pk = doc_id)
    associated_users = current_document.teams.all().users

    ....
```

**Error:** 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'users'

```
associated_users = current_document.items.all().users.all()
```

**Error:** 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'users'

```
associated_users = current_document.items.users.all()
```

**Error:** 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'users'

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, yes. `current_document.teams.all()` is a queryset - more or less, a list - of Teams. It doesn't make sense to ask for `current_document.teams.all().users`, as a queryset doesn't itself have a 'users' attribute, hence the error. `users` is an attribute of each Team element *within* that queryset. So, one way of doing it would be to iterate through the queryset and ask for the users associated with each team.

However, that would be hopelessly inefficient - one database call for each team. A much better way is to ask the database directly: give me all the users who are in teams associated with the current document. Like this:

```
User.objects.filter(team__documents=current_document)
```

Comment: I am still confused.  the Team models association with the Documents model is from documents to team, not the other way round, (I know this is not the most logical approach, but I am not allowed to change the model structure), so how can i filter team__documents?

Comment: @agf 1. No, you use the actual model names inside the filter expression. 2. No, you use = to look up a single element within a M2M/FK relationship. See [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Comment: @Finglish you can access relationships from both sides. See the link I gave to agf.

Comment: OK, still not with you yet though.  I tried the filter as you suggest and I get the error: Cannot resolve keyword 'team' into field

Comment: With the models as you have given them, my query works (I've just copied-and-pasted them into a new app and tried it). Note that pluralization matters - you have `Team` and `Documents`. Also you need to have your app in INSTALLED_APPS for the reference from User to be added.